# Can a disk like object (like UFO's) really fly?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity

UFOs as shown in movies are shown as disk like objects with raised centers that emit some sort of light from bottom. Can such a thing fly?

My very limited knowledge in physics tell me that a disk like object may not be able to maneuver unless it has thrusters on sides and simple light can not be enough to make any object go up in the air.

Is it possible?

Comment: *Can UFO's fly?* ... Either that or the aliens must have a really strong [placekicker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placekicker) on their team

Comment: Yes, there are many ways that allows a disk to fly, beeing lighter then air is one.

Comment: Infact there are many disc-shaped UFO made entirely of air hovering above you right now.

Comment: Ever throw a frisbie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beam propulsion has already been done here on Earth.  :-)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam-powered_propulsion

Comment: http://www.google.com.bh/images?q=lightcraft&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wi&biw=1348&bih=591 so its possible I guess

Comment: Yep, but it's not _just_ the light that provides the propulsion. (Not unless you have a huge amount of it)

Comment: That method is too power consuming. From the page "it takes a megawatt of power beamed to a vehicle per kg of payload". A 10 metric ton UFO would then consume 10 gigawatt. We do not observe that energy exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [flying car](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/6970031.stm)

There is even a [video.](http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=b2e_1188457915)

Answer (score 1):

The light below a UFO is actually ionized air. A light beam would not be visible by itself. According to some witnesses mentioned by [Feindt](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1571747133) the ionized air below is rotating, creating a [Taylor column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_column), which could explain why the heavy flying saucer shaped vehicle doesn't fall down. According to [Hill](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1571747133) pulsating forces can be felt near the UFO. One can imagine that the forces mainly propagates in the weak plasma below the saucer. Hill writes that the saucer type of UFOs tilt to turn.

Electromagnetic radiation beam powered propulsion can not be the case since it would loose too much energy to the ground than can be observed. Light and other radiation might be used to affect the plasma though.

Good reads on the physical aspects of UFOs are

> Paul R. Hill - [Unconventional Flying Objects: A Former NASA Scientist Explains How UFOs Really Work](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1571747133)
>
> Carl W. Feindt - [UFOs and Water: Physical Effects of UFOs on Water Through Accounts by Eyewitnesses](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1450095348)

A credible UFO witness in regard to physical (as well as other) aspects is [Billy Meier](https://www.figu.org/). His stories, photos and drawings are revealing but also very demanding to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In mid 2010, Japan Aerospace Exploration Agency launched IKAROS, a spacecraft that is pushed by the radiation of the Sun.

Explanation: If you consider relativistic effects, light (photons) have no mass, but they can carry momentum $p=h/\lambda$ per photon particle, where $h$ is Planck's constant and $\lambda$ is light's wavelength. So, if UFOs can generate very bright light (very high intensity), theoretically they can push themselves against the gravity.

Comment: Wouldn't that high density light cause everything underneath it to get burnt because of the heat produced?

Comment: Yes, if it says "theoretically", it must work in highly idealized conditions.. but, for the UFO to get an upward thrust, it doesn't matter if the everything underneath it catches fire, (it is like propeling yourself on the ice rink by shooting ammunitions at the wall, you still get the force from recoil even after the wall has destroyed). In the movies we don't see anything that burns, thanks to the imagination of the artists.

Answer (score -1):

The lift works on the craft body by interaction between the curren on which flows through the body surface and the magnetic field of the body center.　”The law on the left Fleming."

Comment: Nope, while you can create forces by electric currents, you are still bound by Newtons laws. You have to overpower the gravity between the UFO and the earth, which means you need to exert a force on earth. The current/magnetic effect you describe would be limited to the UFO itself.